# unicode characters writing to CSV issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, unicode, sql-server-2012

I have this table in a database.

```
create table #temp
(
    name nvarchar(max) 
)
insert into #temp 
(
    name 
)
values
('à¸›à¸ à¸§à¸£à¸´à¸™à¸—à¸£à¹Œ à¹€à¸‰à¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸¢à¹„à¸˜à¸ªà¸‡') 

select * from #temp
```

When I am seeing this data in the website. the data is displaying as

ชญา สวัสดิ์โยธ

But when I am exporting this data to csv it is displaying as

à¸›à¸ à¸§à¸£à¸´à¸™à¸—à¸£à¹Œ à¹€à¸‰à¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸¢à¹„à¸˜à¸ªà¸‡

I want to export the data to csc from sqlserver in the same way that shows in WEB.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003837

Answer (score 0):

This is either (a) an issue with your UTF target (e.g. you are targeting UTF-32 on export rather than UTF-8 / 16) or (b) the db you are using requires a symbolic string for inserting these characters-- sort of like how "??!" is a trigraph for "|".

Comment: UTC - Coordinated Universal Time. UTF - The acronym you meant to use

Comment: we tried with both UTF-8 and UTF-16 csv files. but the result is same  @user4951873

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `N` before inserting your values. You can insert `UNICODE` characters.

```
insert into #temp 
(
    name 
)
values
(N'ชญา สวัสดิ์โยธ')
```